# How to add line break for text in quotes in HTML Div

Tags: html

I have a text in html like this:

```
<div>"Book name is:Testbook"</div>
```

Now I want to put "Testbook" in a newline so it can look like this:

```
Book name is:
Testbook
```

Is there any way to do this? The problem is the original text is enclosed in quotes, which is created by webpage framework.  I can't find a way to remove them.  I have tried use "\n", "\r\n", "<br>", none of them work.

Thank you.

Edit:  This is the result of add <br>:

```
<div>"Book name is:<br>Testbook"</div>
```

And user will see this:

```
Book name is:<br>Testbook
```

It does not work.  The <br> tag show as text on webpage. I think this is because of quotes symbol outside the text

Comment: this question needs more details. If I try `<br>` or `\n` on it, it works without issues. Can you make the issue reproducible?

Comment: I use a framework to generate this html code.  when I use <br>, the html looks like this:  <div>"Book name is:<br>Testbook"</div>.  so does /n or /r.  the trouble thing is all content is enclosed in quotes symbol,  and these newline does not work.

Comment: quotes should not be an issue thats why I said you need to add more details such as stating what framework you use...

Answer (score -1):

Just use `<br />`.

```html
<div>Book name is:<br/>Testbook</div>
```

Comment: "I have tried use "\n", "\r\n", "<br>", none of them work."